# mySQL: Is it possible to perform a query to extract the contents of a multi-column Primary Key?

Tags: mysql

I've searched for an answer to this question but I'm not finding anything. I can see how to set up a multi-column Primary Key. I have also seen many references to inserting a new row using the Primary Key.

But, what I'm not finding is if it's possible to do a simple mySQL query using the Primary Key as the SELECT criteria and have that query provide the contents of the columns used to create the Primary Key.

For example, I have a five column table. Three columns are: position_title_id, emp_id, mgr_id. I have set these three columns up as a Primary Key:

```
PRIMARY KEY(position_title_id, emp_id, mgr_id)
```

Now, is it possible to use some sort of reference to the Primary key to list the contents of these three columns?

Thank you for any direction you can provide.

Comment: have you tried Select position_title_id, emp_id, mgr_id from ....?

Comment: Why? You try to bend SQL somehow. This looks like you are using it wrong.

Comment: No. Of course, you may get the info about the columns list used in PK and apply it in prepared statement form - but this makes no sense I think.

Comment: You mean like SHOW INDEX? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html

Comment: Okay. I'm just new at this but I wondered what, if anything was possible. Thanks for the input. Much appreciated.